# alert when running applications from root

Tags: root, permissions

When I want to launch some applications from root user it alerts me that it may not be run as root and i need to log in as normal user. For example for Google Chrome or Glob database visualization. Why it says so and how can I enable it?

Comment: I can't understand: Are you trying to enable the application being run as root, or are you trying to enable the warning fro every application?

Comment: I would like to run this programs from root

Comment: This is ***not recommended***, for security reasons as in my answer.

Comment: even if it is not recommended how can I enable it

Comment: Please see edits to my post. You can't unless you either remake the program using the existing source, or find a configuration option to disable this check.

Answer (score 3):

This is mainly for security reasons. Software with root access can do *anything* on your system if an attacker manages to get it to execute arbitrary code, which is a common attack. A malicious user can run `apt-get`, change your passwords file keeping you from logging in, or worse, wipe your hard disk and destroy all traces of your data, possibly beyond the help of `ext4undelete` or Photorec. As a limited user, any malicious code will only be able to do what that user can do. Since `sudo` requires a password *at runtime*, the malicious script cannot get it.

Also, if you run a program as a normal user with username `username`, then any data con configuration is stored in a subdirectory of `/home/username`. When you try to run it as root, it looks for and places config files in `/root`, where they won't be seen when you run the program as a normal user. This can cause user frustration if a user unwittingly does this.

In order to enable this on a program that does not allow this, you have two options:

- Find a command-line switch or configuration file that allows you to do this. This may not work on some programs, and is different for every one.
- Recompile the program after editing the source. You must remove the check for the user. This is very difficult and cumbersome.

As stated, there is not much you can do if the program does not have an option for this.